# Best way to store game data on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios

im creating a game that has multiple levels and the levels contain multiple textures and shapes.

What would be the best way to store this data on iphone/ipad?

I was thinking of using SQLite or coredata for storing it. But i also need to implement a function that will update the game data from a remote server (in game purchases). Is SQLite the best way to archive this? How would i then update the SQLite content when updating the content (download a .zip extract it and import into db/directory)? If anyone has any pointers i would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to store them in a plist (which is an xml file). SQLite would require you to store it outside the app sandbox, in the documents directory (because including an sqlite inside the original app is read only).

Other than that, you can use coredata.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the sql sandbox. The problem with plists is that if every update has a its own plist it would be messy to load every plist into the game. And also searching for relations in plist would be slow and a pain.

Comment: (Btw it's app sandbox, not SQL Sandbox--yet :) )Why not serialize your objects and deserialize them in your server. The trick part would be not to serialize them using the standard ios routines. You could then store the data also on server side, in a database and when a user requests the data (for refresh, or having his app reinstalled or just for inquiry) they would be recreated. It seems like reinventing the wheel, but sometime it's a necessity.

Comment: Well i would really like that the client stores the items that came with the update. What i really would like to archive is something similar to how angry birds handle this (u can get new levels via a update).

Comment: I have implemented the same in a subscription based app (External) that requires content to be updated (a big SQLITE file). The trick is to have the udid's or an information stored (somewhat agnostic to conform with the personal data laws and something) to your server and do an inventory there, so that information per user can be retrieved and updated accordingly.

Comment: so if i understand correctly u send a request to a remote server with the device unique id and check which content to load (based on previous updates/purchases)? How does the downloaded content look like (a zip containing a sqlite db)? How do you than store the content inside the application (in a sqlite db)? Would appreciate if you could describe a bit the process of updating & deploying a update (if it's not a secret). Thanks

Comment: The "usual" recipe is that you save the content to /documents or the /library folder that is on the sandbox (via a rest or http request or https request). I think [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis.tasks/understand_utis_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH203-BABHCIAC) can help you. I can't reveal much about how I distribute my files but it's similar.

Comment: Apple is now rejecting apps that access the UDID... http://venturebeat.com/2012/03/25/apple-rejects-udid-apps/

Answer (score 1):

It’s good to think about what SQLite and Core Data bring to the table. Both are very good for querying, but you will mostly only need to fetch objects for given ID? In that case you can also consider a simple file storage. We have used a plist index plus regular files to store some game data, it’s a simple solution with low technical overhead.

Comment: i will need to fetch all the levels and all the levels elements and construct objects (sprites and physics shape) out of them. Thats why i though of using SQLite. And updating content from a remote server would be less of a pain (if i would store all the data in files i would than have to have for each update a new file - which would be a mess if there would be alot of updates)

Comment: I don’t think that SQLite would make loading any easier for you. As for the updates, I can’t exactly imagine your use case, so I can’t comment on that.

Comment: well if i would use SQL, loading would be simple because everything related to the game would be stored in a single database, so the game would intialize from this database. And also updating would be done just by coping the update databases content to the local database (and not from N files).